# How to connect NetEncoder to LinearLayer

Tags: neural-networks

While using Encoder and LinearLayer separately

```
Enc = NetEncoder[{"Class", {"F", "M"}}]
Layer1 = LinearLayer["Output" -> "Real", "Input" -> "Real", "Weights" -> {{1}}, "Biases" -> {-1}]
```

all works properly:

```
Layer1[Enc[{"F", "M"}]]
```

But I failed to build a network `Enc->Layer1` with use of `NetChain` as follows:

```
NetGraph[ <| "L1" -> Enc,  "L2" -> Layer1 |>, {"L1" -> "L2" }]
```

Comment: First of all, avoid using capitalized names of variables as it can interfere with in-built Mathematica symbols. Then, is this what you are looking for: ``enc = NetEncoder[{"Class", {"F", "M"}}]; layer = LinearLayer["Output" -> "Real", "Input" -> enc, "Weights" -> {{1}}, "Biases" -> {-1}]; NetGraph[layer]``?

Comment: Thanks. This works. But why my code is wrong? Formally, NetChain is built from Encoder and one layer.....

Comment: I guess this is just how they are implemented in Mathematica. It seems like they are not treated as a layer, but can only work either as a standalone encoder or be *attached to an input port* (see [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NetEncoder.html), 5th item in Details). It's the same in the [tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksIntroduction.html#19492777409) – encoders and decoders are always *attached* to the input/ouput layer.

Comment: Thank you, this might be so.......

Comment: The code perfectly works for 2 layers (except encoder):
enc1 = NetEncoder[{"Class", {"F", "M"}}];
ClassNet = 
  NetGraph[<| 
    "C1" -> LinearLayer["Output" -> "Real", "Input" -> "Integer", 
      "Weights" -> {{1}}, "Biases" -> {-1}],
    "C2" -> 
     LinearLayer["Output" -> "Real", "Input" -> "Real", 
      "Weights" -> {{1}}, "Biases" -> {0}] |>, 
   {"C1" -> "C2"}, "Input" -> enc1, "Output" -> "Real"];
ClassNet[{"F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M"}]